# A View Over a XML Data Type Column

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, view

I have a table that contains a column of XML Datatype (column name FileContent).  I want to create a view that queries the contents of the XML datatype column so that I no longer have FileContent column but two additional columns called FuelPathwayCode and PhysicalPathwayCode from the underlying XML document.  Is this possible with SQL Server 2008? And, if so, how?  Thanks.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_LC_UploadXML
AS Select
  UploadFileID,
  Year,
  Quarter,
  CompanyID,
  FileType,
  FileContent,
  FileName,
  Description,
  Success,
  AddBy,
  AddDttm
FROM LC_UploadXML
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500166.aspx

Use `FileContent.value('(/FuelPathwayCode/@year)[1]', 'int(4)')` to retrieve the particular field you are looking for.

This is supported in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I am looking to traverse the entire XML document and query all values of the /FuelPathwayCode in one result set?  The [1] is only picking up the first instance.  What do I use to pick up ALL values for the ../FuelPathwayCode?

SELECT FileContent.value('(LCFS-Report/Fuel/FuelPathwayCode)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as FuelPathwayCode
FROM LC_UploadXML

Answer (score 0):

XML has fairly rich support in Sql Server 2k5 and up, a variety of options here. You can try the [xml data type methods](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx) for querying, pulling values from, iterating over nodes in the document, and modifying the content. This is probably the best option for use in a view, in your case you'll likely want to check out the [value method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx).